# What is the logic behind .form file format design?

Tags: swing

IntelliJ IDEA uses .form file format for describing Swing forms.

Let's take *MyForm.form* file as an example (I skip irrelevant content)

```
<component id="d32e0" class="javax.swing.JCheckBox">
    <properties>
        <text value="CheckBox"/>
    </properties>
</component>
```

My question is simple: why not to use attribute "text" instead of tag "text"?

```
<component id="d32e0" class="javax.swing.JCheckBox" text="CheckBox">        
</component>
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be several reasons:

- Using attributes they would have to discern between "property" attributes (e.g. "text") and non-property attributes (e.g. "id", "class") which must be treated differently.
- Using nested structures also allow to set nested properties like `List` or `Map` properties.
- Because the allowed properties are not known upfront it would be hard to define XML validation schemas or DTDs when attributes are used. Using a tag allows to validate the overall structure and only put in a wildcard in the `properties` section.

Comment: 1. just consider all attributes as property attributes; 2. there is no List or Map values for sure; 3. why to validate .form file? just throw exception during runtime instead. Does it make sense? Sorry my English :)

Comment: 4. if tag has "unknown" attribute just skip it

Comment: @KolesnikovichDmitry: 1) not possible - if some custom component _has_ an `id` property - then how would you set it? You just could not without interfering with the forms id. 2) Really? You might take a look at `JList` and a few more. Let alone custom components. 3) Because anyone could write it even with notepad and having the _option_ to validate it using well-known standard tools is better than not having this option. 4) That would be a pretty hackish way to deal with errors.

Comment: @A. H. 1) not allow `id` property for custom tags 2) I mean smth different, we can avoid `properties` tag at all http://collabedit.com/en8cu 3) only 1% of developers wish to write .form files in notepad 4) hackish but simple, okay we can give info in runtime about "unknown" attributes

Comment: @A. H. By the way, there is no XML validation schemas for .form format files right now

Comment: @KolesnikovichDmitry: I don't get your drift. For your own file format and your own frameworks you can use anything you like and impose any restrictions upon the users of your frameworks you like. So you can use attributes if you like. But obviously Idea has chosen to impose as few restrictions as possible, allow flexibility and be open to future improvements. That's stuff framework strife for. If that does not answer your question I did not understand it.

Comment: @ A. H. I just follow your points with out drifting. 1) reserved words is common practice in programming. 2) the intent is to avoid extra tags 3) only 1% of developers wish to write .form files in notepad and there is no XML validation schemas for .form format files right now 4) hackish but simple. To impose as few restrictions as possible does not mean to keep things harder then it can be.

Comment: @ A. H. There are different ways to be open to future improvements. I do not consider the actual way as the best.

Comment: Maybe. Using attributes, forbidding certain names ("reserved words", which is not even possible in this case) and not being able to formally check file structure has proven to be worse.

Answer (score 0):

Then the XML dialect/grammar would have to allow the `text` attribute for every `component` even if the concrete `Component` subclass doesn't support `text`. Logically it would be dependent of the value of the `class` attribute. In fact the `component` tag then would have to allow every possible attribute of every possible class that inherits from `Component` - impossible, as it is open.

The attribute form may look easier for a single value but as soon as more than one attribute value has to be set writing it as list is better readable. But then I think this file is not edited by hand.

If it is not a pure XML dialect than a mix of (undeclared) attribute and list declaration would be possible. In fact the `text` tag in itself smells.